# "new BigDecimal(13.3D)" results in imprecise "13.3000000000000007105.."?

Tags: java, precision, bigdecimal

How is it that Java's `BigDecimal` can be this painful?

```
Double d = 13.3D;

BigDecimal bd1 = new BigDecimal(d);
BigDecimal bd2 = new BigDecimal(String.valueOf(d));


System.out.println("RESULT 1: "+bd1.toString());
System.out.println("RESULT 2: "+bd2.toString());

RESULT 1: 13.300000000000000710542735760100185871124267578125
RESULT 2: 13.3
```

Is there any situation where Result 1 would be desired? I know that Java 1.5 changed the `toString()` method but was this the intended consequence?

Also I realise that `BigDecimal` has `doubleValue()` etc, but the library that I am working with helpfully uses a `toString()` and I can't change that :-(

Cheers.

Comment: Actually the toString() version is probably what you want.  Decimal numbers cannot be properly represented as a double, and while BigDecimals solve this problem, giving them a double in the constructor undermines the solution as they do not have an accurate number to start from.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Well, the [API](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#BigDecimal(double)) does address this apparent inconsistency in the constructor `BigDecimal(double val)`:

> 1. The results of this constructor can be somewhat unpredictable. One might
>      assume that writing new
>      BigDecimal(0.1) in Java creates a
>      BigDecimal which is exactly equal to
>      0.1 (an unscaled value of 1, with a scale of 1), but it is actually equal
>      to
>      0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625. This is because 0.1 **cannot be
>      represented exactly as a double** (or,
>      for that matter, as a binary fraction
>      of any finite length). Thus, the value
>      that is being passed in to the
>      constructor is not exactly equal to
>      0.1, appearances notwithstanding.
> 2. The String constructor, on the other hand, is perfectly predictable:
>      writing new BigDecimal("0.1") creates
>      a BigDecimal which is exactly equal to
>      0.1, as one would expect. Therefore, **it is generally recommended that the
>      String constructor be used in
>      preference to this one.**
> 3. **When a double must be used as a source for a BigDecimal**, note that
>      this constructor provides an exact
>      conversion; it does not give the same
>      result as converting the double to a
>      String using the
>      Double.toString(double) method and
>      then using the BigDecimal(String)
>      constructor. To get that result, **use
>      the static valueOf(double) method**.

Moral of the story: The pain seems self-inflicted, just use [**`new BigDecimal(String val)`**](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#BigDecimal(java.lang.String)) or [**`BigDecimal.valueOf(double val)`**](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#valueOf(double)) instead =)

Comment: +1: That's how Double really works.  Not much to do with BigDecimal.

Comment: Nice one. So really someone should throw a RTFM at me ;-)

Comment: Note that also new BigDecimal(d+"") works fine. Results in "13.3" just like when using valueOf(d)

Answer (score 11):

Your problem has nothing to do with `BigDecimal`, and everything with `Double`, which cannot represent 13.3 accurately, since it uses binary fractions internally.

So your error is introduced in the very first line. The first `BigDecimal` simply preserves it, while `String.valueOf()` does some fishy rounding that causes the second one to have the desired content, pretty much through luck.

Answer (score 8):

You might want to inform yourself about how floating-point values are implemented ([IEEE 754-1985](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985)). And suddenly, everything will become crystal-clear.

Answer (score 5):

This isn't the fault of `BigDecimal` - it's the fault of `double`. `BigDecimal` is accurately representing the *exact* value of `d`. `String.valueOf` is only showing the result to a few decimal places.

Answer (score 3):

Fractions represented with binary number types(i.e. `double`, `float`) cannot be accurately stored in those types.

```
    Double d = 13.3;        
    BigDecimal bdNotOk = new BigDecimal(d);
    System.out.println("not ok: " + bdNotOk.toString());

    BigDecimal bdNotOk2 = new BigDecimal(13.3);
    System.out.println("not ok2: " + bdNotOk2.toString());

    double x = 13.3;
    BigDecimal ok = BigDecimal.valueOf(x);
    System.out.println("ok: " + ok.toString());

    double y = 13.3;
    // pretty lame, constructor's behavior is different from valueOf static method
    BigDecimal bdNotOk3 = new BigDecimal(y);
    System.out.println("not ok3: " + bdNotOk3.toString());

    BigDecimal ok2 = new BigDecimal("13.3");
    System.out.println("ok2: " + ok2.toString());

    Double e = 0.0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) e = e + 0.1; // some fractions cannot be accurately represented with binary
    System.out.println("not ok4: " + e.toString()); // should be 1


    BigDecimal notOk5 = BigDecimal.valueOf(e);
    System.out.println("not ok5: " + notOk5.toString()); // should be 1

    /* 
     * here are some fractions that can be represented exactly in binary:
     * 0.5   = 0.1   = 1 / 2
     * 0.25  = 0.01  = 1 / 4
     * 0.75  = 0.11  = 3 / 4
     * 0.125 = 0.001 = 1 / 8
     */
```

output:

```
not ok: 13.300000000000000710542735760100185871124267578125
not ok2: 13.300000000000000710542735760100185871124267578125
ok: 13.3
not ok3: 13.300000000000000710542735760100185871124267578125
ok2: 13.3
not ok4: 0.9999999999999999
not ok5: 0.9999999999999999
```

Just use **`BigDecimal.valueOf(d)`** or **`new BigDecimal(s)`**.