# How to make one digit after decimal point?

Tags: java, int, double, rounding

Searching how to make two digit after decimal point as below

```
$ = (double) (((int)($ * 100)) / 100.0);
```

Anyone can help to how to make "one digit" after decimal point ?

thanks a lot

Comment: Which language are you using?

Comment: JAVA, i am learning write Android App

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
$ = (double) (((int)($ * 10)) / 10.0);
```

Note: edited after the comment.
If you need java and rounding instead of truncate try this:

```
import java.lang.Math;

double a;
a = ((double) (round(a*10))) / 10.0;
```

This will shift left the dot of one position, round to the nearest integer and then shift the dot back to the right one position.

Edited second time:

What you need is still unclear.
If you are fine with truncate as before:

```
double $=1.24*(double)amount;
$ = (double) (((int)($ * 1000)) / 1000.0);
outelc.setText("ELC(1.24)= " + Double.toString($) + " /pc");
```

If you need rounding:

```
double $=1.24*(double)amount;
$ = (double) ((round($ * 1000)) / 1000.0);
outelc.setText("ELC(1.24)= " + Double.toString($) + " /pc");
```

Comment: yes, you right, thanks so much.but hv some problem.
For example, $14.5t5 , now change to 14.5 , exactly i need 14.6. or another example, $14.54 I need the output is 14.5

Comment: Hi, thanks for your further help, but the code is not workable.pls find the code I edit now, 

    double $=1.24*(double)amount;
      $ = (double) (((int)($ * 1000)) / 1000.0);
      outelc.setText("ELC(1.24)= " + $ + " /pc");

Can you help me review and adv how to edit the code ?

Comment: Are you using $ as a variable name in Java? I know it is allowed, but I've never seen such usage before in Java. It's more offen used in PHP and JQuery, wich is probably the OP's main language.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using doubles to store/calculate currency values, then you will likely find yourself in a world of pain with rounding. Been there, done that, got the scars.

I highly recommend that you use `BigDecimal` values for **ALL** currency values, and do not even involve doubles in the instantiation. Always use the `String` constructor.

See related questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7186204/bigdecimal-to-use-new-or-valueof/9713581#9713581) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/460755/new-bigdecimal13-3d-results-in-imprecise-13-3000000000000007105?rq=1).