# Fastest way to instantiate BigDecimal from string

Tags: java, performance, instantiation, bigdecimal

Consider an application that

1. Reads several thousands of `String` values from a text file.
2. Selects (via a regular expression match) those values that represent a number (from simple integers to very large values written in scientific notation with mantissa).
3. For each `String` value representing a number, instantiates a `BigDecimal` object (at a total rate of thousands of Bigdecimal objects per second).
4. Uses each instantiated `BigDecimal` object for further processing.

Given the above scenario, obviously the instantiation of each `BigDecimal` object has an impact on performance.

One way to instantiate those `BigDecimal` objects from a non-null String `str`, is:

```
BigDecimal number = new BigDecimal(str.toCharArray(), 0, str.length()));
```

which is exactly what the [String constructor of BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#BigDecimal%28java.lang.String%29) expands to in the `Oracle` implementation of the `JDK`.

Is there a faster way of instantiating `BigDecimal` objects from such strings, or via an alternative approach?

Comment: The BigDecimal API shows you the constructors that are available. If you have a concern about this, then consider profiling them.

Comment: I have looked at the constructors, hence the expansion from string to the form presented in the question. What I am wondering is whether there is a simple alternative that I have not thought about yet.

Comment: What else is there besides what is listed in the API? I think that with BigDecimal, you're going to have to accept a performance hit as the price for the greatly improved precision, and that there is no way around this other than to not use BigDecimal and to thus forgo the precision.

Comment: Optimizing `BigDecimal` sound like premature optimization to me. If the *complete* process is really to slow I would also look whether the complete IO handling and, especially, the regexp stuff can be optimized. Regexps are more expensive than most people think at first.

Comment: @Hovercraft: This is more or else what I am asking. For instance, BigDecimal has some valueOf() constructors, which are supposed to be higher performance but are not for String values. My guess is that not much more can be done.

Comment: @A.H. You are right. I was just wondering whether I am missing something obvious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use

```
BigDecimal number = new BigDecimal(str);
```

which is simpler and the difference is unlikely to matter.

If you need performance and you don't need more than 15 digits of accuracy you can use `double` instead.

You need to performance I would look at the performance of your whole application before micro-optimising.  You mention using a regular expression and this can use more CPU than creating strings or BigDecimal. Can you profile your application?

Comment: Agreed on the performance issue. It seems to me that, given the regular expression I need to match anyway, I should check the number string and, if it is not too large (i.e., up to long or double with less than 17 decimal digits) I could use a primitive type directly. As for the constructor, you are right, but the "expanded" version saves 1 method call. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I would agree that difference is unlikely to matter, however I would use [valueOf](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#valueOf%28double%29) as future versions of java are likely going to cache a lot of the common numbers.

Comment: Using valueOf() is indeed preferable, but it does not apply for String values.

Comment: @PNS nothing stops you from parsing to double

Comment: There may be bigger numbers than double and also creating a double and then instantiating a BigDecimal seems too much of an effort.

Comment: Also, involving Doubles in BigDecimal calculations leaves you open to [all sorts of rounding issues](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/460755/new-bigdecimal13-3d-results-in-imprecise-13-3000000000000007105?rq=1).

Comment: @DuncanKinnear I'm not sure if you read the accepted answer, especially the "moral of the story" part.

Answer (score 0):

If there are lots of numbers that are likely to be the same, then maybe a `HashMap<String, BigDecimal>` 'cache' of `BigDecimal` values might be faster.